# How to make the icon's active state (border-bottom: 5px solid red) transition to another icon when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with the active state for each of the icons. What's supposed to happen is that; when the icon is clicked there should be a red line that appears (border-bottom: 5px solid red) under that icon and then when you click on the next icon, the red line on the previously clicked icon disappears and the red line appears on the icon that you just clicked and so on and so forth, but when I click on the other two icons. The red line appears only on the first icon; doesn't matter which one I click.

```js
 function toggleTabs() {
        const tabs = document.querySelector('#tabs');
        tabs.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #e50914;
    --dark-color: #141414;
    --light-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 230px;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--dark-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: grey;
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(70, 65, 65);
}
.tab-1, .tab-2, .tab-3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.content > div:hover {
    color: var(--light-color)
}

#tabs p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}


#tabs.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
 
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e81277d7cc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
 <div class="content">
        <div class="tab-1" id="tabs" onclick="toggleTabs()">
            <span class="fas fa-door-open fa-2x"></span>
            <p>Cancel at any time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-2" id="tabs" onclick="toggleTabs()">
            <span class="fas fa-tablet-alt fa-2x"></span>
            <p>Watch anywhere</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-3" id="tabs" onclick="toggleTabs()">
            <span class="fas fa-tags fa-2x"></span>
            <p>Pick your price</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot have three items with the same ID. JS chooses only the first

Comment: What do I do as a substitute?

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID

Answer (score 1):

Not the best code aby works

```js
function toggleTabs(param) {

        const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
         tabs[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        tabs[param].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #e50914;
    --dark-color: #141414;
    --light-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 230px;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--dark-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: grey;
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(70, 65, 65);
}
.tab-1, .tab-2, .tab-3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.content > div:hover {
    color: var(--light-color)
}

#tabs p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}


#tabs.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e81277d7cc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
 <div class="content">
        <div class="tab" id="tabs" onclick="toggleTabs(0)">
            <span class="fas fa-door-open fa-2x"></span>
            <p>Cancel at any time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="tabs" onclick="toggleTabs(1)">
            <span class="fas fa-tablet-alt fa-2x"></span>
            <p>Watch anywhere</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="tabs" onclick="toggleTabs(2)">
            <span class="fas fa-tags fa-2x"></span>
            <p>Pick your price</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I didn't know that querySelector and querySelectorAll were different. But I wanted to know what you meant by "You cannot have three items with the same ID. JS chooses only the first". Doesn't querySelectorAll just put the elements with the same ids or classes in the same nodelist.

Comment: the same class yes - the same ids no